# How to authenticate Facebook JWT in .Net Core API

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, authentication

I am in the process of creating a mobile app that allows users to log in via Facebook. Once logged in, the app holds on to a Bearer token used to make further requests. I am attempting to pass this token along to a C# .Net Core API. I'm attempting to write as little auth code as possible as doing it myself is prone to huge security issues.

Currently my code in `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer",        
    });

    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions {
        AppId = "****",
        AppSecret = "****",
        SignInScheme = "Bearer"
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

With this, all requests return 401, even with a valid Bearer token. Now I'm not 100% sure `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` is even compatible with `UseFacebookAuthentication`, and if it is I'm sure I'm missing some code here. What steps should I take to get this working?

Comment: Did you try to comment out the JWT part for testing purpose?

Comment: Is it trying to call a web api with FB token?

Comment: http://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/02/06/accessing-facebook-api-using-c/ very handy

Answer (score 1):

I've posted some day ago the same question but I didn't received any answer.
Anyway, googling, I've found the only (?) possible solution.
When your client logged into Facebook, you have to send your Facebook token to a custom endpoint of your server.
This endpoint shall:

- Verify if the token received is valid using Facebook API (very easy)
- Try to log the user using `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` method of `SignInManager<User>` class: `var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(provider, userId, isPersistent: false);` where `userId` is the Facebook id user
- if result.Succeeded is false:

  - Get the Facebook user info using `https://graph.facebook.com/{userId}` endpoint
  - Create a User entity with that information
  - Create the user in the database using `await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, userLoginInfo);`, where `userLoginInfo` should contains the `provider` (Facebook), `userId` (Facebook user Id) and `application`(your app name)
  - Call `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);` to sign the user

You can get the user from the database using `_userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);`

Now your API can returns a token that will be accepted as `Authorization` header